# Add VS icon pack to VS plugin, visual studio plug-ins development

Tags: plugins, icons

I'm creating an add-in for VS, how to add icon getting from VS icon pack for the menu command button?

Getting icon from resource code example

```
<GuidSymbol name="testIcon" value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000}">  
    <IDSymbol name="testIcon1" value="1" />  
</GuidSymbol> 
<Bitmap guid="testIcon" href="Resources\Icon.png" usedList="testIcon1"/>
<Button guid="guidAddIconCmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">  
    <Parent guid="guidAddIconCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />  
    <Icon guid="testIcon" id="testIcon1" />  
    <Strings>  
        <ButtonText>My Command name</ButtonText>  
    </Strings>  
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Known Monikers** - The set of image monikers contained in the Visual Studio Image Catalog and publicly consumable by any Visual Studio component or extension. This one is a good choice, let's try.

- Firstly, include this library `KnownImageIds.vsct` in you .vsct file
- Modify the code to add what icon you need around `<Icon>` tag
- Add flag `<CommandFlag>IconIsMoniker</CommandFlag>`

For example, add VS "open folder" icon to your menu command

```
<Include href="KnownImageIds.vsct"/>
<Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>
<Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>
<GuidSymbol name="testIcon" value="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000}">  
    <IDSymbol name="testIcon1" value="1" />  
</GuidSymbol> 
<Bitmap guid="testIcon" href="Resources\Icon.png" usedList="testIcon1"/>
<Button guid="guidAddIconCmdSet" id="cmdidMyCommand" priority="0x0100" type="Button">  
    <Parent guid="guidAddIconCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" />  
    <Icon guid="ImageCatalogGuid" id="OpenFolder" /> // icon id
    <CommandFlag>IconIsMoniker</CommandFlag>         // enable moniker
    <Strings>  
        <ButtonText>My Command name</ButtonText>  
    </Strings>  
</Button>
```

- Browse Monkier icon id from here [KnownMoniker id text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt628927.aspx#Anchor_11)
- For more visualization, just install this VS add-in [Moniker Browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=misaz.VisualStudioMonikerBrowser)

Comment: @johnson yup, at least for me, tried it for various VS version 2015, 2017